# mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given error

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone help me why I am getting this error `mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in` I have checked everything. Im not sure what seems to be wrong. I also tried to change single quotes to double quotes but still get the same error.

Code is here. Tanks !

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$g_id = 'g_id';
$g_name = 'g_name';

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT g_id, g_name, h_d FROM g_post WHERE g_id = '$g_id'");
$query->execute(array("g_id" => $_GET['game_id']));
$query->bind_result($g_id, $g_name, $h_d);
?>
```

Comment: 1) placeholders need a colon in front of their name + you don't need to quote them 2) You can only pass an array to `execute()`, when you use PDO, not with mysqli_*

Comment: mysqli doesn't support named placeholders either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';

$g_id = 'g_id';
$g_name = 'g_name';

$query = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT g_id, g_name, h_d FROM g_post WHERE g_id = '$g_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$name=( $query) ? mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query) : false;
```

The $con variable would come from your dbconnect.php file, where you've set a connection string and put it into a $con variable or whatever you've called it.

Hope this helps,

Sohail.

Comment: Holy SQL injection, Batman!

Answer (score 2):

MySQLI is more methodic than PDO, first you need place holders(`?`) and not put the the values right at query.

Pass the right type of date in `bind_param()`, `i` integer, `s` string, `d` decimal/interger/float and `b`blob.

Prefere `get_result()` at `bind_result()` with the last one if the query has 20 fields you need declare 20 variables.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT g_id, g_name, h_d FROM g_post WHERE g_id = ?");
$query->bind_param('i', $g_id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['g_id'] . ' - '. $row['g_name'] .'<br>';
}
```

With `bind_result()` you can do in this way:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT g_id, g_name, h_d FROM g_post WHERE g_id = ?");
$query->bind_param('i', $id);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($g_id, $g_name);
while($query->fetch()){
    echo $g_id . ' - '. $g_name .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem. However, it does not echo the variables Im trying to display which are the $h_d and $g_name. I am using `while ($query->fetch())`

Comment: @LostinDigitalWorld if you prefer `bind_result()` it's ok :P i don't like